# Mic not working on Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have been working on Smart Mirror project but I am stuck now. I would like to operate my smart mirror through audio. But my USB soundcard only plays speakers my mic gets detected but doesn't work.

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Raspbian Jessie OS. The USB Soundcard is a QHMPL QHM 623 3D Virtual 5.1 Stereo & Mic QHM623. I have tried going through sites and changing my device settings to USB and I have tried using pavucontrol frequently to understand if the mic gets detected and indeed it does. But when I speak into mic, the control does not operate accordingly.

I tried working in alsa and it does not detect my voice or any sound. The mic is not mute and the volume is kept high enough. Also the settings I changed are enabled for USB device. I don't understand then where is the issue because speakers from same USB sound card seems to work and also give expected output yet microphone doesn't.

This is my first hardware related project and I would really appreciate help.I am new here so apologies if I forgot something.

Really require help.. Thanks in advance.